# Where is this coat of arms from?

Tags: knowledge, visual, real

My father found an old glass during a recent move and has no idea where it's from. It looks vaguely familiar to me (maybe all coats of arms look vaguely familiar), but I've looked up the places we're mostly associated with (universities in the United Kingdom, South Africa, and Zimbabwe, although there are wider possible connections).

[image: glass with coat of arms]

Anyone know where the coat of arms is from?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really a puzzle, it's an identification request. This would be a better fit on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify+coat+of+arms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe - after some searching with keywords involving 'coat of arms with three escallops argent and a book' - this is the crest of:

> [Rhodes University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodes_University) in Makhanda (Grahamstown), South Africa. (Initially found from [this hit](https://dokumen.tips/documents/calendar-2012-558445e167c77.html), noticing the 'Eastern Cape Province' tag and then searching for universities in that area...)
>
>  [image]
>
>  The top line of symbols appears to be a lion between two thistles.

This would fit with your suggestion of it possibly belonging to a South African university...

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's a question for Puzzling, but it appears to be

> Rhodes University in South Africa :

> https://www.ru.ac.za/introducingrhodes/visionandmission/

Comment: Ha, I see you came to the same conclusion - and only a few sections sooner! Two in agreement - I think that's a confirmed hit! :)